# Build OpenID provider check_authentication mode "stateless" using DotNetOpenAuth

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth, provider

I'm building an OpenID provider using **DotNetOpenAuth**, and I need to support stateless mode verification step when the RP return the assertion with mode set to check_authentication and the OP verifies the assertion.

I wonder how to do this step using DotNetOpenAuth ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenID Providers cannot be completely stateless.  They must store associations and nonces.  But aside from these two, check_auth steps are stateless.

Comment: I didn't say that the provider it completely stateless of course, but I was talking about the verification step check_authentication.

Comment: So... I guess my answer answers your question then, right?  If not, please specify what state you're seeing and want to be rid of.

Comment: the sample provided with DotNetOpenAuth doesn't implement the verification step, and we need to have it in our code, so after some trials we couldn't figure out how to do it, do you have any idea ?

Comment: Which sample are you referring to?  All DotNetOpenAuth samples include check_auth support AFAIK.  You may not recognize it when you see it because the library automatically takes care of it all for you.  The samples don't have to explicitly support check_auth because the OP Endpoint in the samples simply forwards every incoming OpenID message to the library and the library supports check_auth internally.